# Netapp TLSv1 handshake failure Issue

Tags: netapp

How to resolve following issue in Netapp

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see NetApp article:
https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1155684/html/GUID-3E07D3F8-6A05-49C0-BF92-9C88BA252E1F.html

All you need is:

options tls.enable on

Be sure to do all cluster nodes.

Good luck.